# Updating a static member in a function call causes crash

Tags: c++, linux, static, constructor

I have a class `polymer` with a `static int count`.
When I create a new `polymer` to add to an array of pointers I am using the `count` to find the correct location in the array and then I update the `count` in the constructor. While compiling in Windows it worked. However, when compiling in Linux (Ubuntu) it crashes unless I remove the updating of the `count` out of the constructor.

WORKS in Windows and Ubuntu:

```
polymerPointer[polymer::count] = new polymer();
polymer::count++;
```

WHEN the constructor doesn't update the static variable (see below)

```
polymer::polymer(){
    //sets up lots of variables but doesn't update the static member
};
```

CRASHES in Ubuntu (works in Windows):

```
polymerPointer[polymer::count] = new polymer();
```

WHEN the constructor does update the static variable (see below)

```
polymer::polymer(){
    //sets up lots of variables and then updates the static member
    count++;
};
```

I can rewrite the code, but I liked not having to remember to update the variable separately, which is why I put the update in the constructor. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: What does debugging say? Where starts the backtrace?

Comment: Show more code, especially how you define that variable, perhaps you forgot to initialize it to 0? Run the program in a debugger, and inspect what happens when it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting undefined behavior.

The following:

```
polymerPointer[polymer::count] = new polymer();
polymer::count++;
```

is not equivalent to

```
polymerPointer[polymer::count] = new polymer();
```

where `polymer()` increments `polymer::count`.

The undefined behavior results from the fact that you're modifying a value and using that value in the same statement:

> **§1.9 p15** If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative
>   to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined.

What probably is occuring is that the count is incremented and then the object is placed in that new position in the array. Now code will access the empty spot left as though it held a valid pointer, or when you get to the end of an array you may try to place the pointer out of the bounds of the array.

It's bad design to put the count increment in a different place than where you actually insert into the array. What you should do is write a static member function that adds elements to the array and updates the count, and then use that instead of manually creating the object and manually placing it in the array, while expecting the count to get updated automatically.

```
class polymer {
    static void create_new_polymer() {
        polymerPointer[polymer::count] = new polymer();
        count++;
    }
};
```

Even better would be to just use a `vector` and have it manage it's own count:

```
polymerPointer.push_back(new polymer());
```

Comment: I realize I should use vector instead of array (but I still think in C and not c++). For now I will implement your idea to make a function that has both new and the count increment. And I will read more about c++ containers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler may legally evaluate `polymerPointer[polymer::count]` before `new polymer();` or the other way around, as it wishes. This means that you cannot depend on `polymer::count` to be the original value. You must use something more deterministic, like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Polymer>>`?

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to an uninitialised variable. Try stepping through the code in a debugger or just printing out the value of `count`.

You could also check that `polymerPointer` points to allocated memory (how much memory did you allocate for the storage and is it enough for all values of `count`?).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the standard doesn't guarantee in which order your statement is executed, so `polymerPointer[polymer::count] = new polymer();` might evaluate `polymer::count` either before or after `new polymer();` is executed.

If you change `polymer::count` inside of `polymers` constructor and `polymer::count` is evaluated after `new polymer()` you obviously skip indices, which is likely what leads to your crashes.

But do you really have any pressing reason to use what seems like a c-style array here instead of using `std::vector` (which would not need the extra `count` variable)? Furthermore if you have the choice you really shouldn't use manual memory management, so use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` if you have access to C++11, `std::tr1::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` otherwise. If you are using boost `boost::ptr_vector` is also an option

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I admit I should bite the bullet and use c++ containers like vector, but I am still stuck thinking in C arrays and can't quite take the plunge. I hadn't heard of unique_ptr or the other ptr classes you mentioned. I will look into those.

Comment: @ColinMatheson: You should really bite that bullet. Particulary the change from c-style arrays to `std::vector` is pretty easy and will spare you a lot of debugging in the long run. Manual resource management is always bug prone and hard to get correct in the face of exceptions (trying to write exception safe code when manually managing resources generally leads to code riddled with `try..catch`). I can only recommend learning to use the c++ standard library to the fullest extend, makes programming in c++ much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix would be to split that assignment in two, hence introducing a *sequencing*:

```
polymer*& insert_point = polymerPointer[polymer::count];
insert_point = new polymer();
```

The reasoning is explained in other answers.